# Importing a java source file in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a project made, but I had to copy and move the java source file to another location in our clear case. If I want that file to be changed when I make further changes how would I do that? It is now a new name so I will probably have to make a new project but I'm not sure how to just import that one source file into the new project or even the existing project.

Update:
I have a project with a package that has some classes in it. I moved the java source file somewhere else and now need to use that file in that location instead of the original. I created a new project and imported the source file. Now it doesn't recognize the package or the class. Its says class "example" is public, should be declared in a file named "example". And the package error says "incorrect package". I'm not sure how to fix this to where The project runs just like the other except uses the file from the other location, so it can stay updated

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Projects tab to open up your projects. Right click the project you wish to import source code from and choose Properties down at the bottom. You will arrive at the Sources tab automatically.

Under Source Package Folders click the Add Folder button to add the folder containing your source. Once it's been added, you will see it appended in the table. You can then double click the row's text under the Label column to edit the way it appears in the browsing window.

Importing this way means that you don't need a new project just to include files from other places on your computer. You can simply browse for the files you wish to include!

Comment: Thank you, I started a new project imported that source file but now my only problem is, how do I get the package imported. Because now it doesn't recognize my package which has my class in it.

Comment: When you pick the source folder, you need to pick the base path folder so that the package is correct.